# Prove or Disprove $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm currently reviewing the topic of subspaces but I'm baffled in this problem. I don't understand the answer provided. May someone please expand on it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem we have $2(1,0,0)^T=(2,0,0)^T \neq (0,0,0)^T$ but $2(1,0,0)^T=(1,0,0)^T + (1,0,0)^T = (0,0,0)^T$ so the two conditions mean that the space is not closed under scalar addition.

For the second problem since $1(1,0,0)^T \neq (1,0,0)^T$ it violates the multiplicative axiom which states that $1x=x$.

Comment: Thank you, I actually realized the 2nd one fails identity axiom and was about to edit, but you answered before me. The first one makes sense now as well.